# UITextField not showing when added as subview in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I'm pretty new to Swift and I'm having some trouble displaying UITextField in SpriteKit. Init() in SceneMenu will not display the UITextField, while using function showTextField() with touchesBegan() works. How can I display UITextField without the user clicking the button Show TextField?

GameViewController.swift:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
 
let scene = SceneMenu(size: view.frame.size)
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
scene.backgroundColor = .white
 
let view = view as! SKView
view.presentScene(scene)
 
}

}
```

SceneMenu.swift:

```
class SceneMenu: SKScene {

override init(size: CGSize) {
 
super.init(size: size)
 
let btnAlert = SKLabelNode(text: "Show TextField")
btnAlert.name = "btn_text"
btnAlert.fontSize = 20
btnAlert.fontColor = SKColor.blue
btnAlert.fontName = "Avenir"
btnAlert.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
addChild(btnAlert)

let textFieldFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
let textField = UITextField(frame: textFieldFrame)
textField.backgroundColor = SKColor.blue
textField.placeholder = "Type name"

view?.addSubview(textField)
 
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
 
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 
}

func showTextField() {
 
let textFieldFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
let textField = UITextField(frame: textFieldFrame)
textField.backgroundColor = SKColor.blue
textField.placeholder = "Type name"

view?.addSubview(textField)
 
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
 
if let touch = touches.first {
   
  let location = touch.location(in: self)
  let action = atPoint(location)
   
  if action.name == "btn_text" {
     
    showTextField()
     
  }
   
}
 
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKScene has a method that lets you setup the scene when you move to it. So, instead of using the custom class's initializer, override and use SKScene's didMove(to view: SKView) method. An example:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        showTextField()
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it works ! I've learned to use init() and I understand that there are 3 ways to create a scene in SpriteKit - init(), didMove and sceneDidLoad. But I can't understand to separate the 3 ways.

Comment: init is called when creating the object itself. You should not use this for setting up and adding subviews. sceneDidLoad is called when the scene is presented (now necessarily by a view).  didMove is called when the scene is prevented by a view such as when the SKView presents your SKScene--which makes it preferable for creating and adding the contents for the scene. If you ever want to test out  and visualize when these are called, write print statements in the functions and watch when they appear in the console at different stages of your app.

Comment: Chris, do you think you could help me with this issue maybe?

[link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707150)